# Comparing lines in a file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to compare File 1 and File 2.

File 1:

```
7.3 0.28 0.36 12.7 0.04 38 140 0.998 3.3 0.79 9.6 6 1
7.4 0.33 0.26 15.6 0.049 67 210 0.99907 3.06 0.68 9.5 5 1
7.3 0.25 0.39 6.4 0.034 8 84 0.9942 3.18 0.46 11.5 5 1
6.9 0.38 0.25 9.8 0.04 28 191 0.9971 3.28 0.61 9.2 5 1
5.1 0.11 0.32 1.6 0.028 12 90 0.99008 3.57 0.52 12.2 6 1
```

File 2:

```
5.1 0.11 0.32 1.6 0.028 12 90 0.99008 3.57 0.52 12.2 6 -1
7.3 0.25 0.39 6.4 0.034 8 84 0.9942 3.18 0.46 11.5 5 1
6.9 0.38 0.25 9.8 0.04 28 191 0.9971 3.28 0.61 9.2 5 -1
7.4 0.33 0.26 15.6 0.049 67 210 0.99907 3.06 0.68 9.5 5 -1
7.3 0.28 0.36 12.7 0.04 38 140 0.998 3.3 0.79 9.6 6 1
```

In both files the last element in each line is class label.

I am comparing if the class labels are equal.
ie compare the classlabel of

```
line1:7.3 0.28 0.36 12.7 0.04 38 140 0.998 3.3 0.79 9.6 6 1
```

with

```
line2:7.3 0.28 0.36 12.7 0.04 38 140 0.998 3.3 0.79 9.6 6 1
```

Matches.

compare

```
line1:7.4 0.33 0.26 15.6 0.049 67 210 0.99907 3.06 0.68 9.5 5 1
```

with

```
line2:7.4 0.33 0.26 15.6 0.049 67 210 0.99907 3.06 0.68 9.5 5 -1
```

Not matches

**Updated**

What I did is

```
String line1;
String line2;
int notequalcnt = 0;
while((line1 = bfpart.readLine())!=null){
found = false;
while((line2 = bfin.readLine())!=null){               
     if(line1.equals(line2)){
          found = true;
      break;
     }
   else{
    System.out.println("not equal");
    notequalcnt++;
   }
}
```

}

But I am getting every one as `not equal`.

Am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: could there be whitespace at the end of one of the lines? Perhaps a `line1.trim().equals(line2.trim())`?  Also, the `!= true` is unnecessary.  Just say `!line1.equals(line2)`

Comment: @Kirby: I think whitespace is not the reason.Now what it is happening is first line of file1 is comparing first line of file2,then second line of file1 with second line of file2.As both these files are not in the same order it is showing notequal.I need to compare line1 of file1 with all the lines in file2 till it reaches the same line then compare the classlabel

Comment: @JasonC:spliting classlabel or comparing each line will give the same result.Is'nt it.

Comment: Your logic has way to many issues to be covered adequately in a single answer. I recommend working out your algorithm on paper then trying this again. (By the way, you say you need to "need to compare line1 of file1 with all the lines in file2 till it reaches the same line then compare the classlabel", but that doesn't make much sense. You wouldn't need to compare the "class label". If the lines are equal then you already know the class labels are equal.)

Comment: +1 Previously u was telling instead of comapring line ,I should split the classlabel and compare.But in both the cases also we will get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first iteration itself, line2 becomes null. So, the loop will not execute again... Declare line2 buffer after the first while loop. Use this code:

```
public class CompareFile {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

   String line1;
   String line2;
   boolean found;
   int notequalcnt =0;

   BufferedReader bfpart = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));

   while((line1 = bfpart.readLine())!=null){
    found = false;
    BufferedReader bfin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
    while((line2 = bfin.readLine())!=null){

        System.out.println("line1"+line1);
        System.out.println("line2"+line1);
        if(line1.equals(line2)){
            System.out.println("equal");

            found = true;
            break;

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not equal");

        }
    }
    bfin.close();

    if(found==false)
      notequalcnt++;
    }
    bfpart.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing every line from file 1 with every line from file 2, and you are printing "not equal" every time any one of them doesn't match.

If file 2 has 6 lines, and you are looking for a given line from file 1 (say it's also in file 2), then 5 of the lines from file 2 won't match, and "not equal" will be output 5 times.

Your current implementation says "if *any* lines in file 2 don't match, it's not a match", but what you really mean is "if *any* lines in file 2 *do* match, it *is* a match". So your logic (pseudocode) should be more like this:

```
for each line in file 1 {
   found = false
   reset file 2 to beginning
   for each line in file 2
      if line 1 equals line 2
          found = true, break.
   if found
      "found!"
   else
      "not found!"
}
```

Also you describe this as comparing "nth line of file 1 with nth line of file 2", but that's not actually what your implementation does. Your implementation is actually comparing the first line of file 1 with every line of file 2 then stopping, because you've already consumed every line of file 2 in that inner loop.

Your code has a lot of problems, and you probably need to sit back and work out your logic on paper first.

Comment: spliting classlabel or comparing each line will give the same result.Is'nt it

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni Yes, and as described above, that's not your fundamental issue.

Comment: Also you say you need to "need to compare line1 of file1 with all the lines in file2 till it reaches the same line then compare the classlabel", but I don't understand this. You wouldn't need to compare the "class label". If the lines are equal then you already know the class labels are equal.

Comment: +1 Previously u was telling instead of comapring line ,I should split the classlabel and compare.But in both the cases also we will get the same result

Comment: Yes, I said that, but that was a minor note that I added at the end of the list of problems above.

Answer (score 0):

If the target is to compare and find the matching lines. Convert the file contents to an arraylist and compare the values.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file1.txt"));
ArrayList<String> file1_list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    file1_list .add(s.next());
}
s.close();

s = new Scanner(new File("file2.txt"));
ArrayList<String> file2_list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    file2_list .add(s.next());
}
s.close();

for(String line1 : file1_list ){
    if(file2_list.contains(line1)){
       // found the line
    }else{
        // NOt found the line
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to compare it using file itself :)

Comment: what do you mean by "file itself"?

Comment: I am trying to compare both files line by line

Comment: IF your goal is to compare the contents of the files, then take the file contents into an array and then do an array comparison will be more effective. I believe your while loop inside first while loop will not work as readLine will reach the end of file and may not move to the start of line unless specified after the first iteration.

Comment: but even if our file is of large size,whether array cope with that .say 1 gb file

Comment: 1 gb file you may need to check the performance. Try to use a database or something. Looping simply through a 1 gb file also face a performance constrain i hope. Your implementation is looping through the whole of second file to check each line of the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Check Apache file Utils o compare files.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html